# Specific purpose language in cpp, having trouble defining keyword

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, keyword

I want to make a specific purpose language in cpp and i am looking to make this syntax:

```
let name2 = object[ values val1, val2, val3... ];
```

Where both let, object and values are keywords.

My first approach was to use operator overload on [], to have object take all arguments but i couldnt manage to get it in the above form.

Comment: Right now overloads of `operator[]` can only take one argument. Looks like that's currently [slated to change](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Array_subscript_operator) in C++23, but that's not available right now.

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes, but literally nothing is preventing OP from implementing this behavior in his own language.